# How can I inherit from a class that is in another .xcodeproj in my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, inheritance

I have a `.xcodeproj` inside my project.  I have a class that I want to have inherit from a class in that `.xcodeproj`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried doing it? How did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: I added a new class and had it inherit from that class, then when I ran, it failed and said it didn't recognize that class.

Comment: Did you: 1. Clean the build after adding the other project? 2. Follow any instructions on the other project for including it (like adding libraries to the main target)?

Comment: I just figured it out.  When I added it to the `Header Search Paths` in my Build Settings, the path I added was wrong.  I changed it to `$(SRCROOT)/myProject` when I had `$(SRCROOT)/Frameworks/myProject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. When I added the .xcodeproj to the Header Search Paths in my Build Settings, the path I added was wrong. I changed it to $(SRCROOT)/myProject when I had $(SRCROOT)/Frameworks/myProject